# Does GURPS Thaumatology require GURPS Magic?

Tags: magic, gurps, gurps-4e

If I picked up the sourcebook *GURPS Thaumatology*, would I need *GURPS Magic*? There seem to be a lot of negative reviews of 4th-edition *GURPS Magic* and nothing but rave reviews of *Thaumatology*.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

According to "Introduction: Current Cross-References" (*GURPS Thaumatology*, p. 5), the book is designed to stand alone and doesn't need *GURPS Magic*. The book presents alternatives to the spell system provided in the Basic Set, as well as some modifications of the default spell system.

*If* you are using the spell-magic rules from the Basic Set, then *GURPS Magic* will be relevant (though not needed), but you could easily turf the generic spell system entirely and implement magic in your game world with one of the *Thaumatology* magic system alternatives.

Answer (score 19):

*Thaumatology* is a magic-system construction guide. You're very unlikely to be using the whole of the book in one campaign, any more than you'd be using all of *Fantasy* or *Space*. Some of its advice is relevant to games with *Magic*-style spellcasting, other bits aren't. So the answer is "it depends on the sort of magic you want in your game".

If you want something like traditional dungeon-bash magic, lots of showy stuff achieved relatively quickly, you'll want *Magic*; if you want to tweak it in detail, you'll also want *Thaumatology*. (The downsides of *Magic* are mostly that the text wasn't sufficiently proofed before publication, so much of it is the same as in the 3e magic books with some of the old bugs still present, and the artwork is a bit naff.)

If you want subtle magic that takes a while (as in the old *Voodoo* and *Spirits* books), or if you want potentially world-altering magic like the sort of thing you'd meet in a *Mage* campaign, you won't need *Magic* too.

Comment: I spent a summer taking a sabbatical from working, and decided to write myself a version of *Mage the Ascension* for *GURPS* 4th edition, using the rules from *Thaumatology*.  It's an absolutely awesome  "magic-system construction guide" - and well worth the money to any GM wishing to dabble in that sort of thing.